# Disabling buttons during API call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to, on a button click, disable the button while I run a function which calls an API, when it has completed I want to re-enable the button.

I've tried a few variations such as `attr()`/`removeAttr()`, as well as the one below with both `$(this)` and `$('#miss')`, but the strange thing is when I only have the disabling line the button disables, when I have disable followed by enable such as in the code below the button never disables. What am I missing?

```
$('#miss').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);

  registerShot('miss');

  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Make `registerShot`, whatever it is, return a Promise, and then call `.then` on it or `await` it and *then* re-enable the button.

Answer (score 1):

If your `registerShot` fucntion is written with no issue, this will help you:

```
$('#miss').click(function() {
  let missButton = $(this);
  $(missButton).prop('disabled', true);

  registerShot('miss')
    .then(function(res) {
      $(missButton).prop('disabled', false);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is being called asynchronously, so the button *is* being disabled, but then being re-enabled immediately after calling registerShot.

You could pass the element to registerShot then re-enable it in the at the end of the function:

```
$('#miss').click(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            registerShot('miss',this);
        });

function registerShot(p1,e) {
  //CodeHere
  (e).prop('disabled', false);
}
```